# Android Studio unit testing - android.net.Uri is missing

Tags: android, unit-testing

I cannot use android.net.Uri in my local unit tests (run in Android Studio on a development machine). Im aware that this is because unit tests are execute against a "thin" android.jar with stubs that only throws exceptions, but this makes it really impossible to test anything that is resource related (files, urls, etc).

I has the same issue when testing a code that uses json, and in order to solve it i added a dependency in my build.gradle :

> testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'

Any similar solution for android.net.Uri ?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution - https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin.

I guess even google are aware of this problem and recommending the same solution - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=145068.

Answer (score 2):

The full answer would be:

1. Add the plugin to your buildscript dependencies:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
           classpath 'de.mobilej.unmock:UnMockPlugin:0.6.0'
        }
   }
```

2. And this to the module's build script:

```
    apply plugin: 'de.mobilej.unmock'
```

3. Add classes you want to keep

```
    unMock {
        keepStartingWith "libcore."
        keep "android.net.Uri"
        keepAndRename "java.nio.charset.Charsets" to "xjava.nio.charset.Charsets"
    }
    
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
```

And here is a code for the test which runs as expected

```
public class WearableUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testUri() throws Exception {
        final int nodeId = 1000;
        final String resourcePath = Params.WEATHER;
        Uri wearableResourceUri = DataWearInteractor.getUri(nodeId, resourcePath);
        assertEquals("Uri should be equal", "wear://" + nodeId + resourcePath, wearableResourceUri.getPath());
    }
}
```